# zeroclipboard edit data before copy to clipboard

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard

I need to use zeroclipboard to copy table to clipboard. But I need also to edit that table, by adding columns, before I move it to clipboard again.

```
I use that code but nothing happened:

<code>
    var clientTarget = new ZeroClipboard( $("#target-to-copy"), {
        moviePath: "ZeroClipboard.swf",
        debug: false
    } );   
    clientTarget.on( "aftercopy", function (e) {
     var editedTable=;
     clipboard.setData( "text/plain",  editedTable);*/
    });
</code>

I run example on localhost server.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want yo edit data before copy it you have to use the [beforecopy](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/jquery.zeroclipboard#example-1-using-beforecopy) event: I suppose you can also modify you table inside too.